# Проблемы с фильтром QSqlRelationalTableModel->setFilter

Tags: c++, sql, qt5

Такая проблема - есть  две связанные таблицы SQLite в двух QTableView связанные с таблицами БД через QSqlRelationalTableModel. Каждая запись во второй таблице связана с одной из записей в первой таблице. Надо сделать так, чтобы выбрав строку в первой таблице, во второй отображались только записи связанные с выделенной строкой первой таблицы. Код выглядит так:

```
void MainWindow::on_tableViewStudyPlansList_pressed(const QModelIndex &index)
{
int col = 3;
int row = index.row();
QModelIndex idx = ui->tableViewStudyPlansList->model()->index(row, col);
QString plan_name = ui->tableViewStudyPlansList->model()->data(idx).toString();

modelStudyPlan->setFilter(QString( SECTABLE "." SECTABLE_PLANNAME "='%1'").arg(plan_name));
//modelStudyPlan->setFilter(QString( SECTABLE_PLANNAME "='%1'").arg(plan_name));
//modelStudyPlan->setFilter(QString( "PlanName = '%1'").arg(plan_name));
modelStudyPlan->select();
}
```

Проблема в том, что хотя значение поля из записи первой таблицы выбирается правильно, во второй таблице исчезают все записи, а не только не совпадающие с выбранным значением в ячейке. Выбор идет именно по той ячейке, по которой таблицы связаны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всем привет! Додумался я до правильного ответа. Хитрость состоит в том, что поскольку поля таблиц связанные, то в ведущей таблице это строка VARCHAR, а в ведомой таблице индексируемое поле типа INTEGER. Следовательно надо придумать как конвертировать правильно произвольную строку в индекс. Я, для начала, решил использовать номер строки в первой таблице, но поскольку в QTableView строки нумеруются с 0, а в БД с 1, то номер надо увеличить на 1. Следующий код работает:

```
void MainWindow::on_tableViewStudyPlansList_pressed(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    modelStudyPlan->setFilter(QString( SECTABLE "." SECTABLE_PLANNAME "='%1'").arg(QString::number(index.row() + 1)));
    modelStudyPlan->select();
}
```